# Organizing eventlogs into folders

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I want to create multiple services and I want them to log each in a log entry under the same directory/folder that I specify so when I open Windows Event Viewer I can see them all placed in one folder. For example service1 would log into service1_log, service2 would log into service2_log and both service1_log and service2_log would reside in one folder named Myservices.
I haven't found anything in Windows Event Log API or any other API that would fit into this problem..I can see in windows event viewer there are folders but I can only create logs into the root of the logs hierarchy there.

Thanks in advance
Tomas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Event Log does not log into directories. However, the event log is split into several logs (*Application*, *System*, *Security* etc.) that are presented as folders in Event Viewer. You can create your own log that will appear as a separate folder in *Applications and Services Logs* (assuming Windows Vista or later) by calling [`EventLog.CreateEventSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a.aspx).

However, I will not recommend that you create your own log. Instead you can let your services log to the *Application* log. By letting each service use a separate event source you can easily filter the *Application* log to only only display the interesting log messages. Again assuming Windows Vista or later you can create a custom view below the *Custom Views* node and filter it by source. This folder will then only show log messages from your services.

---

Fast forward five years: Now, it is quite easy to create you own log that can be seen in `Application and Services Logs` by using the [`EventSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx) class which allows you to create events for [Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx). ETW is highly configurable, has very good performance but can also be a bit difficult to use initially. Message size is limited, installing a new manifest requires administrative rights, while channels like *Diagnostics* are collecting data you can't view the log etc. But all in all ETW is a good alternative to logging to the *Application* event log.

Comment: OTOH, having a custom log makes it very easy to move around. Plus, I've found that most admin prefers custom services to have their own log - especially when it's verbose. This way it doesn't pollute the standard Applications log and there's less risk of losing some previously logged events from other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it is not easily accomplished using the .NET 4 framework.  It looks like .NET 4.5 offers better support for this, but is is not terribly simple.  You can put them into folders per application, but putting those folders in a common folder would be a lot more complex.

See the following answser on another thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10528920/848419