# Referencing sub log folder

Tags: vb.net, event-log, event-viewer

I wonder how I can reference an event log in a sub folder like the one below. I have tried various alternatives but non has been working so far.

```
Dim ev As New EventLog("Microsoft-Windows-AAD/Operational")
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a hierarchy of lognames in the Windows event system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428158/how-do-i-create-a-hierarchy-of-lognames-in-the-windows-event-system)

Comment: I assume that you want to *write* to the event log in question. If that is the case, I have found a duplicate and linked your question to it. If it isn't, please accept my apologies.